# What is the product of reaction between 3,3-dimethyl butanal and SeO2 followed by conc. OH- ions?

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbonyl-compounds, nucleophilic-substitution, carbocation

[image]

So basically first step will be replacement of $\ce{-CH2 -}$ by a ($\ce{=O}$ bond) making a aldehyde and ketone side by side. Now what should I do after this? I tried attacking the aldehyde first as it is more electrophilic. I think both carbonyl groups will be attacked because of high concentration of hydroxyl ($\ce{OH-}$) ions. I even tried dehydration of  the formed product after attacking with $\ce{OH-}$ ions but I always end up with a ketone and a carboxylic acid by its side  after this.

Comment: First is Riley oxidation, then is cannizzaro reaction.

Comment: oh! damn that was simple thanks T-T

Comment: @Zenix Please avoid answering in comments, it is not aligned with our site policy. This is a good example of a homework question, so I don't see why you shouldn't try answering it. ;)

Comment: Is  answer  of this question B?

Comment: @WilliamR.Ebenezer Thanks for the encouragement, I am (and was) quite busy, will try to answer within a day.

Comment: @WilliamR.Ebenezer Answered within 23.30 hours ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the first step, Riley Oxidation (selenium dioxide-mediated oxidation of methylene groups adjacent to carbonyls) is taking place. You will get **A** as:
[image]

**A** on reaction with conc. $\ce{OH-}$ (i.e. in strongly alkaline condition) undergoes redox reaction (famous Cannizzaro reaction). And terminal aldehyde will be oxidized to form the metal salt of acid, ketone will be reduced to form the alcohol, note that intramolecular reaction is taking place, to finally form the product **B**.